# deserialization using jackson objectmapper fails when json has additional fields.How to solve?

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

Thanks in advance. I am using version 1.9.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>


org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.
jsonMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES , false);
JsonNode listNode = jsonMapper.readTree(json);
Iterator<JsonNode> it = listNode.getElements();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode moNode = it.next();
            String className = moNode.get("objectClass").asText();
            String moNodeText = moNode.toString();               
            Class<?> moClass = Class.forName(className);                      
            Object ob = jsonMapper.readValue(moNodeText, moClass);                
            MyObject mo = (MyObject) ob;
            moSet.add(mo);
        }
```

But it keep failing pointing to additional fields in json.

```
(was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: com.xxx.MyObject["additional_field_Json"])
```

I tried parser but got same error. any help?

thanks

Gopi

```
2 >>>> nodeText :{"objectclass":"com.xxx.xxx.MetaInfo$Flow",............,"fieldonlyexistinjson":["VALUE1","VALUE2","VALUE3"],"subFlows":[]}

    2014-04-23 17:39:48,549 - ERROR main com.xxx.xxx.TestMetaDataCache.testImportMetadataFromJson (TestMetaDataCache.java:86) exception 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException) (through reference chain: com.xxx.xxx.Flow["objectTypes"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializer.java:1462)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:699)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1279)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser.readValueAs(JsonParser.java:1336)
    at com.xxx.xxx.TestMetaDataCache.testImportMetadataFromJson(TestMetaDataCache.java:80)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the same exception: "UnsupportedOperationException" is not what you get for unrecognized property. Can you include full stack trace for exception?

My guess is that you have an immutable List or Map somewhere, and deserializer is trying to add entries to it.

Comment: HI STAXMAN, Thanks for reply. I added stacktrace to my question.

Comment: and one more thing is: if I remove field from json, everything works fine.

Comment: Have a look at property "objectTypes" (something set with `setObjectTypes()` most likely) in class `Flow`. and see what happens in setter. This has nothing to do with unrecognized properties, whatever the problem is, but Jackson is delegating exception that setter of that class has.

Comment: Also, you probably want to upgrade Jackson version: 1.9.13 is the latest patch for 1.9. Lots of bugs have been fixed since 1.9.2.

Comment: much appreciate your replies. Upgraded to 13. still hitting problem. I don't have any setter methods in new class as objectTypes is totally removed. So, my why json mapper still considers when i set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=false is still my confusion. If ignored then unsupported exception wouldn't even arise.

Comment: @user823136 I am not sure why you are so convinced that that setting has anything to do with the problem -- I don't think it does. So focus on object structure you do have, and try to get stack trace of embedded exception. That will point the actual problem. "UNSUPPORTED" != "Unrecognized"; Jackson never uses term "unsupported", rather, it comes from java.util and indicates that some type of operation (adding to a List) is not implemented.

Comment: 2 reasons why I want to find this configuration. 1) I downloaded source code and debugged with brake points at ALL places where UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES occur. But its never intercepted. 2) There are NO immutable fields and I played by adding additional fields to JSON as well as to Class structure. And it is NOT ignoring unknown fields and failing. So I can't simply rely on this mapper to build objects. And process becomes more painful because object specific logic has to be coded to build objects which is really lot of code in my case.